# Travel in your country

Tags: word-choice

If you are talking about your native country  and you need to say that you have never traveled, is it wrong to use "in" to talk about your country as it is used in my first sentence? I added the rest of the text for more context.

> So far, I have only managed to travel in Georgia.  My favourite place here is Mount Kazbek. It used to be an active volcano, which has long since died out. At the foot of the mountain there is the Trinity Church. It contains the cross of  Saint Nino. On the way to the top of the mountain ( added there) *there* is the monastery of Betlemi.

Comment: Yes, you can speak of travelling in a country (your own or any other) to refer to going to different places within it.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me if the rest of the text is also correct and I should have indeed added "there"?

Comment: We normally use _there is_ when we first refer to the existence of something  ('There is a church near my house'). However, it would not be wrong to omit _there_ when you begin the sentence with the location. 'Near my house is St. Mary's Church'.

Comment: I wasn't sure "contains the cross" is correct. Should I leave everything as it is?

Comment: If the cross is inside the church then _contains_ is fine. If it stands in the churchyard or on top of the tower then you would need some other form of words..

Comment: I could use "there is" but what would a native speaker use?

Answer (score 1):

"In" is possible and you can speak of travelling "in" your own country.  You could also use "around".  "So far I've only travelled around Georgia".